# Collection of Equivalence relations

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations

I'm lazy about retyping the question so I put a screenshot of it here: [Munkres, Topology, Chapter 1, section 3, problem 5(b)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dhMVf.jpg).

Let $\{R_i\}_{i \in I}$ be a collection of equivalence relations with index set $I$ on a set $A$.  Let $R=\cap_{i\in I} \{R_i\}$.  I want to show that this is again an equivalence class.

To show $R$ is an equivalence class I need to show that it is reflexive, symmetric, and transitive.

Reflexive:  I attempted this one but got some circular reasoning.

Symmetric:  Let $(x,y) \in R$.  Then $(x,y) \in R_i$ for all $i \in I$.  Since each $R_i$ is an equivalence relation on $A$, $(y,x) \in R_i$ for all $i$.  So $(y,x) \in R$.

Transitive: Let $(x,y), (y,z) \in R$.  Then $(x,y), (y,z) \in R_i$ for all $i \in I$.  Since each $R_i$ is an equivalence relation on $A$, $(x,z)$ is in each $R_i$.  So $(x,z) \in R$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

But it's exactly the same reasoning as with symmetry and transitivity!

$$\forall\,a\in A\,\,\wedge\,\,\forall\,i\in I\,\,,\,\,(a,a)\in R_i\Longrightarrow (a,a)\in\bigcap_{i\in I}R_i$$

Comment: This is so elegant and simple.  I just keep reading it over and over again.  Is the rest of my proof ok?

Comment: I think you mean that for every $a \in A$, we have $\forall i \in I\,(a,a)\in R_i$ and therefore $(a,a) \in \bigcap_{i\in I} R_i$.

Comment: @TrevorWilson , isn't that what I wrote?

Comment: What you wrote isn't grammatical because the part of the left of "$\wedge$" is not a formula.  But also on the right of "$\wedge$" I think you may want parentheses around "$\forall i \in I\, (a,a)\in R_i$".

Comment: Because of course we don't want to say that the implication $(a,a)\in R_i \implies (a,a) \in \bigcap_{i\in I} R_i$ holds for all $i \in I$.

Comment: Even though I think that is unimportant, I don't understand: $\,\wedge\,$ is a logical connective (or whatever the correct english term is. I mean the logical conjuction) , and the use of parentheses, outside the sometimes annoyingly narrow walls of logic, are pretty free, imo. I could have written in words but that takes too much time.

Comment: I can't see how that in your last comment could be inferred from my answer, @TrevorWilson

Comment: A logical connective should connect two formulas, but "$\forall a \in A$" is not a formula.  The formula $p \wedge q$ is true if and only if $p$ is true and $q$ is true.  What would it mean for "$\forall a \in A$" to be true?

Comment: I agree that my incorrect interpretation is a stretch, by the way, but I think your correct interpretation is also a stretch.